# How Do I Call these two functions FORECAST.ETS and FORECAST.ETS.CONFINT in Access VBA Code

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I want to use FORECAST.ETS and FORECAST.ETS.CONFINT by calling the following references in my VBA code in Access:

{
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Forecast.ETS(...)

Excel.WorksheetFunction.Forecast.ETS.CONFINT(...)
}

However, I got Complier Error as "Argument Not Optional". I came across Tools -> References in the top Menu bar but failed to find a corresponding reference for me to check to use. Excel.WorksheetFunction.Forecast works fine, but Excel.WorksheetFunction.Forecast.ETS and Excel.WorksheetFunction.Forecast.ETS.CONFINT cannot be found.

Does anyone know which reference(s) to click to check in the reference list so I can call these two functions?

Thank you.

Comment: hmm.. try square-bracketing them, and using the late-bound version: `Excel.Application.[Forecast.ETS.CONFINT]`

Comment: Thank you, Mathieu. I got "Error 2029" as the return value of the calling structure you provided. Can you please advise? I am using Access 2010. If possible, please also take a look at this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/how-do-i-call-these-two-functions-forecastets-and/5084e55d-8988-4bc0-9d52-da36722387cf?messageId=01a2ea2a-9ccf-46c9-a6ce-de52ad7f3245

Comment: Looks like a worksheet error value (e.g. `#VALUE!`). Verify that the actual function works with the parameters you're giving it.

Comment: According to this page, there are so many reasons that can cause #NUM! errors. I might have to check one after another. https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-functions/excel-forecast-ets-function

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel-Blog/Create-Forecasting-Models-using-Excel-and-Machine-Learning/ba-p/91816) and numerous other sources such as [this](https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-forecast-ets-function.html) the Ets functions were first introduced in Excel 2016, so are not available in earlier versions of Excel.

> In Excel 2016, we introduced native ETS functionality.  This includes
>   both a set of new functions such as FORECAST.ETS and other supporting
>   functions for additional statistics.  Your dataset does not need to be
>   perfect, as the functions will accommodate up to 30% missing data.

For 2016 I was able to use Evaluate e.g.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim app As Excel.Application
    Set app = New Excel.Application
    Debug.Print app.Evaluate("FORECAST.ETS(42125,{1,2,3,4},{42005,42036,42064,42095})")
    app.Quit
End Sub
```

---

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim app As Excel.Application
    Set app = New Excel.Application
    Debug.Print app.Evaluate("FORECAST.ETS.CONFINT(42125,{100,250,390,450},{42005,42036,42064,42095}, 95%)")
    app.Quit
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you QHarr. I got "Error 2029" as the value for Debug.Print according to your code. I substituted TODAY() with {5} and '5', respectively, and got "Error 2029" and "Error 2015" as the return, respectively. With my own parameters, I was only able to get error 2029. Please help.

Comment: FWIW `Application.Evaluate` does the same thing as square-bracketing =)

Comment: You get the same problem with the current examples?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sorry didn't see your comment. Was busy testing. Happily delete this.

Comment: Huh, don't! I posted a *comment*, you posted an *answer* - and your answer is good! I'm just pointing out something, not shooting down your answer! ;-)

Comment: @QHarr I copied and pasted your code and executed it in a newly created blank module and I got "Error 2029" for both functions. Please advise. My Version is "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.0; MS Office 2010". Thank you.

Comment: I am working with 2016. I will have a look to see if it has a version dependency. Do they work directly in your Excel application? I.e. in an  excel worksheet?

Comment: I am using ACCESS 2010. And no, they don't. I tried "=FORECAST.ETS(C82,B78:B81,C78:C81)" in the Excel 2010 and got #NAME? error. I guess it is a version dependency issue. Forecast.ets even didn't show up in the calling list automatically, nor did forecast_ets.

Comment: I think that likely. I am still looking for official  confirmation

Comment: So I am afraid the answer is it is only available for 2016+

Comment: Oh, you found it? Can you please share the official confirmation page link if so? Thank you.

Comment: The best link so far is the Microsoft one in my answer

Comment: Sorry I did vote but since my reputation score is less than 15, my vote to your answer did not show up publicly, QHarr. But I still express my appreciation here to you and all other contributors.

Comment: That’s ok. Appreciate it. If answered you can still accept the answer by hitting the check mark. If you need something better drop a note here and I will keep looking.